# Showing value after "While" from ACF repeater field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Im trying to show custom post array by ACF repeater field ID-s.

I only get one value from $value, ex:

'post__in' => array(905)

But it should be: 
'post__in' => array(15, 905, 1, 2, 3)

```
<?php
if( have_rows('take_away_order') ):
while ( have_rows('take_away_order') ) : the_row();
  $value = get_sub_field('food');
?>    
<?php endwhile;?>        
<?php if (is_tax() || is_category() || is_tag() ){
$qobj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 999,
    'post_type' => 'menuu_toit',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'post__in' => array($value),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $qobj->taxonomy,
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $qobj->term_id
        )
    )
);
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting $value in each loop iteration, of course only the last value “survives” that way. Make $value an array to begin with (`$value = [];` before the loop), and then add new elements to it inside, `$value[] = …` And no `array($value)` then either, otherwise you’d get an array of arrays.

Comment: $value[] = .. - this should be done in While?

Comment: Yes, inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it,

```
 <?php
 if( have_rows('take_away_order') ):
    $value = [];
  while ( have_rows('take_away_order') ) : the_row();

  $value[] = get_sub_field('food');

 ?>    
 <?php endwhile;?>        
 <?php if (is_tax() || is_category() || is_tag() ){
 $qobj = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
 $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 999,
    'post_type' => 'menuu_toit',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'post__in' => $value,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $qobj->taxonomy,
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $qobj->term_id
        )
    )
 );
 }
```